# how to use raw_input value for hostname

Tags: python

How do I take the raw input and use that as the "host" in the scp function?

```
host = raw_input('Hostname: ')
filename = "/Volumes/Data/puppet/puppet-enterprise-3.0.1-el-6-x86_64.tar.gz"

os.system("scp filename username@${host}:/home/username")
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(host)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('tar -zxvf /home/username/puppet-enterprise-3.0.1-el-6-x86_64.tar.gz')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your line slightly:

```
os.system("scp filename username@{0}:/home/username".format(host))
```

The `format()` function will replace `host` for `{0}`.

Comment: And preferably not use `os.system` but rather use `subprocess.call()` instead.

Comment: Well said. I don't remember the last time I used os.system()

Comment: Well, I am just learning python, so I've not advanced to all of the other modules yet.  That new format seemed to work.  I'm checking on how to use the subprocess.call() function now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the command by concatenating the host in between. This should work:

```
os.system("scp filename username@" + host + ":/home/username")
```